# C# - InstallUtil - Service failing to launch

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I have a service in C#, that seems to fail to startup, I have created a screenshot below:

Is it the case that the service returns (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN) that it is not loading up?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNq5l.png

Answer (score 0):

Code would be helpful.  From my experience that is because what ever you are calling in the service startup method doesn't end.  That method needs to return.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run heavy task on service startup.If the method in OnStart takes much time to complete then service couldn't start.If this is your scenario change your code on startup with some background worker from tools list available.